# iOS app behaviour after updating to new version

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store-connect

My application runs in background on significant location change event.
When I get this event, app is sending some data to my server. Like current version of the application and other info.

I am facing one issue related to app store. Previous version of the app was 1.1 on App store. I released new version 1.2 on App store. Application is automatically updated to v1.2. I didn’t open app after auto update.

As app runs in background on significant location change event, I am getting data through web service. But app is still sending old data info like old version number i.e. 1.1 to server. Is that means new version code hasn’t reflected as I haven’t open the application after auto update?

Comment: That would be quite strange. When a new app version is installed, I am not completely sure, but I think that the old one is automatically removed. And the new one doesn't launch till the user opens it. AND if they have iOS 7, then the SLC does not work when the app is not running on background. There could still be a possibility for iOS 6 in the following (improbable) scenerio: iOS 6 doesn't require the app to be opened by the user, and the app is notified by SLC whenever there is a SLC. So, if the old app version wasn't removed till you opened the new one, that would reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's working fine on iOS 6 after updating from 1.1 to 1.2. On iOS 7.1 it's not showing the same behavior as iOS 6.

Comment: So, you mean the problem is specific to iOS 7?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it on iOS 6.1.6, The problem is iOS 7 specific.

Comment: Well, I have no specific clue. I would ask to the Apple software team, in the Apple forums how that could be. We don't know enough about the Significant Location Change service to understand what may be originating the problem.